# Оптимизация сложного MYSQL запроса

Tags: mysql, база-данных, join, group-by

Имеется mysql запрос который выводит список продуктов в корзине

на входе имеется `guests_carts`. id_guest

в котором есть поля     id  id_storage  id_guest    quantity
которая в свою очередь смотрит в "склад" по id_storage

склад это products_storage с полями id  id_product  vendor  quantity    cost    price   price_ws1   price_ws2   price_ws3
у склада есть id_product    который привязан к товару products

у которого есть поля    id  status  order   id_category id_brand    id_quantity_name    id_default_storage  name_ru name_uk name_en desc_ru desc_uk desc_en badge_config    badge_ru    badge_uk    badge_en

так же есть картинки products_images
у которых есть поля     id  id_product  order   file_name

из которых на каждую позицию в корзине надо выбрать ОДНУ картинку, которая соотв. id_product и при этом имеет минимальный order

я пытался вставить WHERE в подзапрос  SELECT `products_images`..... но не знаю как передать в подзапрос id_product, а в данный момент каждый раз полностью выгружаются все картинки для последующего выбора, что как по мне очень негативно повлияет на производительность...

```
SELECT `tmp_carts`.`quantity` , `tmp_storage`.`id` , `tmp_storage`.`id_product` , `tmp_storage`.`price` , `tmp_storage`.`price_ws1` , `tmp_storage`.`price_ws2` , `tmp_storage`.`price_ws3` , `tmp_images`.`file_name` , `tmp_products`.`name_ru` , `tmp_products`.`name_uk` , `tmp_products`.`name_en`
FROM `xs_sport`.`guests_carts` AS `tmp_carts`
LEFT JOIN `xs_sport`.`products_storage` AS `tmp_storage` ON `tmp_carts`.`id_storage` = `tmp_storage`.`id`
LEFT JOIN (

SELECT `products_images`.`file_name` , `products_images`.`id_product`
FROM `xs_sport`.`products_images`
ORDER BY `products_images`.`order` ASC
) AS `tmp_images` ON `tmp_storage`.`id_product` = `tmp_images`.`id_product`
LEFT JOIN `xs_sport`.`products` AS `tmp_products` ON `tmp_storage`.`id_product` = `tmp_products`.`id`
WHERE `tmp_carts`.`id_guest` =7
GROUP BY `tmp_carts`.`id`
ORDER BY `tmp_carts`.`id` DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Извините если не достаточно понятно объяснил вопрос, я впервые тут пишу от безысходности

Низкий поклон человеку с ником Akina, чутка доработав его запрос вот что вышло:

```
    SELECT tmp_carts.quantity , 
       tmp_storage.id , 
       tmp_storage.id_product , 
       tmp_storage.price , 
       tmp_storage.price_ws1 , 
       tmp_storage.price_ws2 , 
       tmp_storage.price_ws3 , 
       ( SELECT tmp_images.file_name
         FROM products_images AS tmp_images
         WHERE tmp_storage.id_product = tmp_images.id_product
         ORDER BY tmp_images.order ASC LIMIT 1 ) AS file_name,
       tmp_products.name_ru , 
       tmp_products.name_uk , 
       tmp_products.name_en
FROM ( SELECT *
       FROM guests_carts 
       WHERE id_guest = 7
       ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3 ) AS tmp_carts
LEFT JOIN products_storage AS tmp_storage ON tmp_carts.id_storage = tmp_storage.id
LEFT JOIN products AS tmp_products ON tmp_storage.id_product = tmp_products.id;
```

Comment: Не знаю как в MySql, но обычно можно первую запись из этого запроса где `ORDER BY 'products_images'.'order` взять через `TOP` или через `LIMIT` - в разных версиях SQL по-разному пишется. Судя по тому, что у вас в конце написано `LIMIT 3`, соответственно в том запросе надо написать `LIMIT 1` да и всё. Хотя нет, как-то всё сложнее несколько должно быть, но как именно - надо сообразить...

Comment: limit 3 в самом низу просто ограничивает количество выводимых продуктов, по логике в подзапросе да, надо limit 1 но тогда оно не проходит все картинки а останавливается на первой и тогда выводит null а всё потому что я не знаю как сделать выборку во вложенном запросе (как передать туда `tmp_storage`.`id_product` ) я кстати не уверен возможно ли это в принципе =(

Comment: Как минимум возможно несколько вариантов как это всё сделать. Можно сначала сгруппировать по  id_product  в этом  запросе и взять max(order), а потом сделать ещё один JOIN, который будет брать order = вот этому max(order) ну и id_product  = id_product  из того запроса где max. Можно так, кажется. Вообще ORDER BY во вложенных запросах - это уже как-то неправильно, обычно достаточно MAX, MIN и т.п.

Comment: Если нужна именно оптимизация запроса, как указано в заголовке - то следует: 1) Убрать сортировку в подзапросе - она всё равно будет проигнорирована; 2) Заменить ```FROM `xs_sport`.`guests_carts` AS tmp_carts``` на подзапрос с LIMIT - незачем лопатить всю таблицу, если нужны всего три записи.

Comment: Укажите точную версию MySQL.

Comment: *на каждую позицию в корзине надо выбрать ОДНУ картинку, которая соотв. id_product и при этом имеет минимальный order* Сделайте это коррелированным подзапросом с соотв. сортировкой и лимитированием в списке вывода.

Comment: Вот так? Кстати тоже работает и уже получше как по мне
 (SELECT MIN(`products_images`.`order`), `products_images`.`file_name`, `products_images`.`id_product`
 FROM `xs_sport`.`products_images`
GROUP BY `products_images`.`id_product`


 ) AS `tmp_images`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Навскидку получается что-то вот такое:

```
SELECT tmp_carts.quantity , 
       tmp_storage.id , 
       tmp_storage.id_product , 
       tmp_storage.price , 
       tmp_storage.price_ws1 , 
       tmp_storage.price_ws2 , 
       tmp_storage.price_ws3 , 
       ( SELECT tmp_images.filename
         FROM products_images AS tmp_images
         WHERE tmp_storage.id_product = tmp_images.id_product
         ORDER BY products_images.order ASC LIMIT 1 ) AS filename,
       tmp_products.name_ru , 
       tmp_products.name_uk , 
       tmp_products.name_en
FROM ( SELECT *
       FROM guests_carts 
       WHERE id_guest = 7
       ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3 ) AS tmp_carts
LEFT JOIN products_storage AS tmp_storage ON tmp_carts.id_storage = tmp_storage.id
LEFT JOIN products AS tmp_products ON tmp_storage.id_product = tmp_products.id;
```

Бэктики и алиас БД удалены.

Comment: Это гениально, спасибо Вам огромное, исправил пару мелких ошибок и этот шедевр заработал)))